# Unable to pass parameters to controller in POST AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I cannot pass parameters to controller action in ajax POST request. There is my code :

```
 $("#sendSubCatButton").click(function(){
    var catId = $("#category_name").data("id");
    var subCatName = $("#sous_category_name").val();
    var lvlUrgenceMax = $("#sous_category_lvl_urgence_max option:selected").val();
    // alert(catId);
    // alert(subCatName);
    // alert(lvlUrgenceMax);
    $.ajax({
      url: '/sous_categories',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
          name: subCatName,
          category_id: catId,
          lvl_urgence_max: lvlUrgenceMax
      }
    });
  });
```

And my controller (only the parts concerned) :

```
  def create
    @create_new_subcategory = verifRight('create_new_subcategory')
    if @create_new_subcategory
      @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
      @sous_category = SousCategory.new(sous_category_params)
      # Any category have a 'lvl_urgence_max', for those who create an incident.
      # With that, we can determine how many an incident is important.
      @sous_category.lvl_urgence_max.nil? ? @sous_category.lvl_urgence_max = 10 : false
      respond_to do |format|
        if @sous_category.save
          format.json { render json: @sous_category.id, status: :created }
          format.html { redirect_to edit_category_path(@category), notice: 'Vous venez de créer une sous catégorie.' }
        else
          format.json { render json: @sous_category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Impossible de créer la sous catégorie.' }
        end
      end
    else
      renderUnauthorized
    end
  end
```

...

```
  def sous_category_params
    params.require(:sous_category).permit(:name, :category_id, :lvl_urgence_max)
  end
```

In console there are that :

> Started POST "/sous_categories" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-31 16:08:56
>   +0200
>   Processing by SousCategoriesController#create as HTML
>   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"EDqyXaq+2PekfJrLrmn/+16AnirzvySD+hkZj5+cQee2JD2ddMudDRJWXlZkCfKJ3mzw2AWuVAeCPr/y0Y1WVw==", "sous_category"=>{"name"=>"efsefesf", "lvl_urgence_max"=>"10"}}

EDIT : I commented the "alerts" but I can see the value of the var "CatId" in the alert popup but it is not passed.

Comment: try this, remove datatype: json from ajax code

Comment: Nope ... `{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"bQo4y190JEC//p1gf7RBdE0LOS1BvBQ9KnzntZ5lLO7LFLcLgQFhugnUWf211EwGzedX37etZLlSW0HI0HQ7Xg==",
 "sous_category"=>{"name"=>"efsefesfesf",
 "lvl_urgence_max"=>"10"}}` and I also tried with datatype: script and nope too ...

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = {"data": {
          "name": subCatName,
          "category_id": catId,
          "lvl_urgence_max": lvlUrgenceMax
          }};

      $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/sous_categories',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json'
            });
```

Comment: Aaaaaand ... Nope .... : `var data = { "data": {
              "name": subCatName,
              "category_id": catId,
              "lvl_urgence_max": lvlUrgenceMax
            }};

    // alert(catId);
    // alert(subCatName);
    // alert(lvlUrgenceMax);
    $.ajax({
      url: '/sous_categories',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
  });`

Comment: I have `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Category with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/sous_categories_controller.rb:72:in 'create'`
`

Comment: Then probably your params[:category_id] - catId is not correct. Try in your rails console and see if it return a value for category_id which you are passing.